# PHP and MYSQL check for update "error"

Tags: php, mysql, rows-affected

While editing a mysql database row, I normally like to check if the action was successful before I redirect my user. Normally I use the following:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $queryu);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) {
    // Success
    redirect_to("local_federations.php?local={$local_id}");
} else {
    // Fail
    echo "<p>Failed to edit the Local Federation</p>";
    echo $queryu;
    echo "<p>" . mysqli_error($connection) . "</p>";
}
```

The problem is, sometimes the user don't change anything on the data, and click "Save Changes" anyways. On this case, the `mysqli_affected_rows` return 0 (I guess it does) and then I receive the error part of my `IF` statement, because no rows were affected.

This is all done through an edit button next to a customer name that leads to edit the customer information through an html form.

Would you suggest a better approach for this, making it so it ignores in case no changes were made? Or a way it update the data regardless were any fields were changed?

Comment: What is your `$queryu` query? and why you are testing with connection affected rows `if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection)`

Comment: `mysqli_error()` ?

Comment: How about adding a `last_modified` column to your database? So it gets modified no matter what

Comment: Check the value of $result. It's FALSE if it failed. Regardless of total affected rows.

Comment: change if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) to if (mysqli_affected_rows($result).

Comment: I like the last modified idea, it would always update the data. And I'm sorry, but the syntax of mysqli_affected_rows(connection) is the right one.

Comment: It didn't fail to update on the $result. The query is alright, I guess the problem is mysql recongnizes that since no changes were made to the data, no rows were affected.